# How to get the file path of the current theme?

Tags: python, scripting, customization, path, theme

I have an addon that allows changing your current theme to a custom one using `bpy.ops.preferences.theme_install(path)`, but I also want to allow going back to the previous theme (just in case).

The previous theme won't always be the Blender Default so `bpy.ops.preferences.reset_default_theme` isn't that useful. Ideally, I would want to store the path of the current theme, perform the switch, and then re-use the path if the user ever wants to switch back.

Anyone know how to get the path of the current theme or something that can be of similar use?

Comment: Blender doesn't keep the path to the theme once it has loaded the theme.

Comment: Sagde, thanks anyway.